# Google Apps Script - Automatically add multiple rows to some selected sheets in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to automatically add 'for example' 500 rows to the last rows in several selected sheets in google sheets using Google App script and this will be time-driven trigger every week. tried all script related to it here, none append the rows. there any App script that does that function?

Comment: I see no way to process _selected_ sheets. You have to define the list of the sheets somehow. It could be a list of names or IDs or indexes, or something else. As for the rest I'm sure it can be done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it by sheet names, set to a time-based trigger.

```
// By Name - Only Specified Sheets
function addRows() {

  const includeSheets = [`Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `etc`]

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
                .filter(sheet => includeSheets.includes(sheet.getName()))
                .forEach(sheet => {
                  sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getLastRow(), 500)
                })

}

// By Name - Exclude Specified Sheets
function addRows() {

  const excludeSheets = [`Sheet1`, `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `etc`]

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()
                .filter(sheet => !excludeSheets.includes(sheet.getName()))
                .forEach(sheet => {
                  sheet.insertRowsAfter(sheet.getLastRow(), 500)
                })

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how it could be done:

```
function add_rows() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  var sheets_indexes = [0,1,2]; // get the list of sheets by their indexes

  for (let i of sheets_indexes) {
    let sheet = sheets[i];
    let last_row = sheet.getLastRow() || sheet.getMaxRows();
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(last_row, 500);
  }
}

function set_trigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('add_rows').timeBased().everyWeeks(1).create();
}
```

Script takes list of sheets by their indexes and add 500 rows after the last row. With the function `set_trigger` you can set the time driven trigger that will run the script every week.